# Function return union type constrained based on parameter union

Tags: typescript, constraints, union-types

I have a function that maps a set of strings from an external source to our API enums.

```js
type AllPossibleUnits =
  | 'mm'
  | 'cm'
  | 'in'
  | 'ft';

enum Units {
  millimeters = 'millimeters',
  centimeters = 'centimeters',
  inches = 'inches',
  feet = 'feet',

function convertUnits(unit: AllPossibleUnits) {
  switch (unit) {
    case 'mm': return Units.millimeters;
    case 'cm': return Units.centimeters;
    case 'in': return Units.inches;
    case 'ft': return Units.feet;
  }
}
```

Now, in a few cases I need to apply these transforms when the unit type is a subset of AllPossibleUnits, such as just metric units. In those cases if input is `'cm' | 'mm'` I'd like to constrain the return type to the matching `Units.millimeters | Units.centimeters` so that:

```js
function getMetricUnit(): 'mm' | 'cm' {
  // call external API and validate return is 'mm' or 'cm'
}

const units = convertUnits(getMetricUnit());
// type of `units` should be `Units.millimeters | Units.centimeters` instead of just `Units`
```

Is this possible without some crazy TypeScript magic? I've tried using various combinations of generics for the input parameter as well as return type of `convertUnits` but can't seem to satisfy the compiler in any of my attempts.

Comment: `'mm' | 'cm'` is not `AllPossibleUnits`, is it? Maybe it makes more sense to add a type for that with a meaningful name. i.e. `MetricUnits` and `ImperialUnits` for `'in' | 'ft'`? Then `AllPossibleUnits = MetricUnits | ImperialUnits`

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of 'crazy TypeScript magic'. It is possible (admittedly by duplicating some of the logic form the function to a conditional type)

```
function convertUnits<T extends AllPossibleUnits>(unit: T) : {
  'mm': Units.millimeters,
  'cm': Units.centimeters,
  'in': Units.inches,
  'ft': Units.feet,
}[T]
function convertUnits(unit: AllPossibleUnits) {
  switch (unit) {
    case 'mm': return Units.millimeters;
    case 'cm': return Units.centimeters;
    case 'in': return Units.inches;
    case 'ft': return Units.feet;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnACgewM6oJYCM4QKoB2GwqUAvALABQUUAPlAOQC2zj1tDjAxmx-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-IZxagQkDEHx1dzUAAVopAwXFvmgA)

Or if you put the mapping in an object type, we can reduce some of the duplication:

```
const unitMap = {
  'mm': Units.millimeters,
  'cm': Units.centimeters,
  'in': Units.inches,
  'ft': Units.feet,
} as const
function convertUnits<T extends AllPossibleUnits>(unit: T) : typeof unitMap[T] {
  return unitMap [unit]
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnACgewM6oJYCM4QKoB2GwqUAvALABQUUAPlAOQC2zj1tDjAxmx-UwwF2NAYwBmwRgG5q1CAQCuzKIWKkA3v2YYEGZhGAQATqTJMdeg0dOMANP24Lg+wybNMnBF9ff3+QtwAFhAejIEhqP6i4hCG5EyxhtEAvnJU3MgEqMBQikTAALIAhmAJWqIsbABcqgWoAHSWcK42qA6VvIy1aiQNXj5uph204cI99Q0RoSOJUhPqDUnAHSlQxaSZ2cDU4vncLllQWwBuJsC9qAA8ACpQEAAeRgQAJqTwSGiYOPj1AHwACnyxFqNwAlFBaqBIMhxHkCiUwABtG4AXSgFVoxkMimMBHhxERUCRwOAqOoaSo6T2BAOGCOAHNDIVDMYMNxegCwbUqowxF0MfxscBcfilAgAISyKiU6hbHIEkgJU7nS4AplFVnszlgsHSgD0+qg0OgsKgAANSahzVBUEFkIo4C8oFhoObLk1dC1fKYBB6Bq13DahDkIMVnWaAFaKBXu+rmoA)